# how to multisplit dataframe column and assign identical column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

one of the columns in dataframe contains one of the following

`Last online: 03H 17M<br>Level: 155<br>Followers: 89<br>Grenades: 447`

or

`Level: 155<br>Followers: 89<br>Grenades: 447`

With split I can make columns but depending of online status the position is different

`df['Userdata'] = df['Userdata'].str.split('<br>').str[0]` 
--> gives --> Last online: 03H 17M   or Level: 155

How can I split the data that:
`str[0] is empty or 03H 17M (depending on name Last online available or not) str[1] is 155 str[2] is 89 str[3] is 447`

any help would be apriciated

Comment: What is your expected output from the two lines you posted?

Comment: Can you include an [mcve] and a printout of your dataframe so we can see what exactly you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use str.extract for that purpose.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

```
import pandas as pd

#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['Last online: 03H 17M<br>Level: 155<br>Followers: 89<br>Grenades: 447', 
                     'Level: 155<br>Followers: 89<br>Grenades: 447']})

extract = df.col.str.extract('(?:Last online: (.*)(?:<br>))?Level: (\d+)<br>Followers: (\d+)<br>Grenades: (\d+)')

print(extract)
```

This yields:

```
         0    1   2    3
0  03H 17M  155  89  447
1      NaN  155  89  447
```

Comment: Thank you just tried it and added it to the export.
It workes as described thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the job?:

```
import pandas as pd
def chk_first(data):
    if (data[0].startswith('Last')):
        data.pop(0)
    return data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Userdata': ['Last online: 03H 17M<br>Level: 155<br>Followers: 89<br>Grenades: 447', 'Level: 155<br>Followers: 89<br>Grenades: 447']})
df['Userdata'] = df['Userdata'].str.split('<br>').apply(lambda x: chk_first(x))
df
```

If you want to seperate the values to columns:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.Userdata.tolist(), index= df.index)
```